# What's the difference between GetColumnBaseName and GetColumnName in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In order to retrieve database column name, there are two methods: `GetColumnBaseName` and `GetColumnName`.

1. What's the difference between them?
2. Why `GetColumnName` requires `StoreObjectIdentifier` with *custom* values for table name? Doesn't `Metadata` know the table based on its parent `PropertyEntry` property?

```cs
using var db = new TestContext();
var customer = await db.Customers.FirstAsync(c => c.Id == 1);
customer.Address = "Jon";
var entry = db.Entry(customer);
var modifiedProperty = entry.Properties.First( p => p.IsModified );

// Using "GetColumnName"
var baseName = modifiedProperty.Metadata.GetColumnBaseName();

// Using "GetColumnName"
// Doesn't Metadata know the table?
var id = StoreObjectIdentifier.Table("customer", schema: "dbo");
var columnName = modifiedProperty.Metadata.GetColumnName(id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. if you see in the EF code in github you see they do the same things, GetColumnName if not find columnName call GetDefaultColumnName that he call GetDefaultColumnBaseName()... at the end they do the same things:

```cs
        /// <summary>
        ///     Returns the name of the table column to which the property is mapped.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="property"> The property. </param>
        /// <returns> The name of the table column to which the property is mapped. </returns>
        [Obsolete("Use the overload that takes a StoreObjectIdentifier")]
        public static string GetColumnName(this IProperty property)
            => (string?)property.FindAnnotation(RelationalAnnotationNames.ColumnName)?.Value ?? property.GetDefaultColumnName();

        /// <summary>
        ///     Returns the base name of the column to which the property would be mapped.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="property"> The property. </param>
        /// <returns> The base name of the column to which the property would be mapped. </returns>
        public static string GetColumnBaseName(this IReadOnlyProperty property)
            => (string?)property.FindAnnotation(RelationalAnnotationNames.ColumnName)?.Value ?? property.GetDefaultColumnBaseName();


        /// <summary>
        ///     Returns the default table column name to which the property would be mapped.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="property"> The property. </param>
        /// <returns> The default table column name to which the property would be mapped. </returns>
        [Obsolete("Use the overload that takes a StoreObjectIdentifier")]
        public static string GetDefaultColumnName(this IProperty property)
        {
            var table = StoreObjectIdentifier.Create(property.DeclaringEntityType, StoreObjectType.Table);
            return table == null ? property.GetDefaultColumnBaseName() : property.GetDefaultColumnName(table.Value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Returns the default base name of the column to which the property would be mapped
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="property"> The property. </param>
        /// <returns> The default base column name to which the property would be mapped. </returns>
        public static string GetDefaultColumnBaseName(this IReadOnlyProperty property)
            => Uniquifier.Truncate(property.Name, property.DeclaringEntityType.Model.GetMaxIdentifierLength());
```

[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/901bfb495371109ab4f7b3339bd42e95421404e1/src/EFCore.Relational/Extensions/RelationalPropertyExtensions.cs#L42)

2. GetColumnName () still returns the name of a column that has been mapped to a property, but this behavior is now ambiguous because EF Core 5 supports TPT and simultaneous mapping to a view or function where these mappings might use names of different columns for the same property.

[Link to Microsoft directive](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/901bfb495371109ab4f7b3339bd42e95421404e1/src/EFCore.Relational/Extensions/RelationalPropertyExtensions.cs#L42)

Comment: Thanks! I got the first point. About second point - that is the reason they are `Obsolete`? 

Comment: Yes...that a recap of Microsoft directive.. :)

Comment: I change the answare with link

Comment: I know what is `Obsolete`.  BTW, the link leads to `GetColumnBaseName`. 